# Get full path to site action within SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I'm wonder how can I build full path to the action within my signalR hub. I have code in my hub:

```
public string GetUpdateUrl(string identifier)
{
     var helper = new System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
     var result = String.Empty;
     try
     {
         result = helper.Action("Download", "Agent", identifier);                          
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         var t = e;
     }
         return result;
 }
```

What I want is just to return full url (like example.com/Conteroller/Action?identifier=some_code) to the action.

And here Download action

```
 public ActionResult Download(string identifier)
 {
       //return download
 }
```

But I'm getting error.

**Response is not available in this context.**

Comment: How about passing it alongside your identifier?

Comment: `Response is not available in this context.` there is no `Response` word in your code.. are you missing anything

Answer (score 0):

Since your SignalR service is self hosted by owin (isn't it?), you shall try to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33520474/1097429) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33085913/1097429) answers.