# OWIN WEB API self host resolve path to folder

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin

Form inside an **ApiController**. I need to read content of a file embedded inside the project. But I can't resolve the correct path

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage DoSomething()
{
    String content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"~\SomeFolder\file.txt");
}
```

Doing like this the resolved path point to:

> C:...\bin\Debug\~\SomeFolder\file.txt

instead of

> C:...\SomeFolder\file.txt

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this under **OWIN** Self Host?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it does not make sense to try to access a file inside a project. All the files necessary for deployment (dlls, assets, txts,...) should be copied to a separated folder so that when we need to deploy, we just need to copy that folder.

You should set the file as **Copy To Output** and try:

```
String content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"SomeFolder\file.txt");
```

which is resolved to

```
C:...\bin\Debug\SomeFolder\file.txt
```

To make the code work with OWIN, you could take a look at this answer [How do you resolve a virtual path to a file under an OWIN host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571258/how-do-you-resolve-a-virtual-path-to-a-file-under-an-owin-host). It suggests using [HostingEnvironment.MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx) and falling back to manipulating file paths manually in self host scenario.

Comment: I'm trying to send an html formatted email so I need to grab the html template somehow and substitute the required parts. I would have used Server.MapPath("~/SendMail.htm") but under Owin self host I have not this option any other options you are aware of?

Comment: @Gavello: Owin does not run inside IIS, so `Server.MapPath` should not be possible. If you host owin inside IIS, maybe you can try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557122/microsoft-web-api-how-do-you-do-a-server-mappath . If you make your files relative to your root in both console host and IIS host, the solution in this answer should also work.